# Using dbus in python without using a shell command

Tags: python, dbus

This is what I have done cause I can't figure out how to use the dbus library
This script polls my mouse's DPI for when it gets changed by the button on the mouse and sets it to something usable then prints the current DPI to a [KDE widget](https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/do-it-yourself-bar) but I am using the subprocess library cause I can't figure out how to use the dbus library

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from openrazer.client import DeviceManager
from time import sleep
from subprocess import run as call
from sys import argv
if len(argv) == 1:
    print("No DIY bar ID given!")
    quit()
ID='/id_'+argv[1]
dev=DeviceManager().devices[0]
l_out=0
while True:
    if not dev:
        sleep(3)
        if DeviceManager().devices[0]:
            dev=DeviceManager().devices[0]
        continue;
    dpi=dev.dpi
    if dpi[0] == dpi[1]:
        if dpi[0] == 1800:
            dev.dpi=(900,900)
        elif dpi[0] == 4500:
            dev.dpi=(1000,1000)
        elif dpi[0] == 9000:
            dev.dpi=(1100,1100)
        elif dpi[0] == 16000:
            dev.dpi=(1200,1200)
        out=str(dev.dpi[0])
    else:
        out=str(dpi[0])+','+str(dpi[1])
    if not l_out == out:
        call(['qdbus','org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar',ID,'org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar.pass','|A|<img src="/usr/local/share/icons/diybar/mouse.svg" height="22"/>'+out+' DPI|'+dev.name+'||'])
    l_out=out
    sleep(0.7)
```

example shell command

```
qdbus org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar /id_10 org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar.pass '|A|<img src="/usr/local/share/icons/diybar/mouse.svg" height="22"/>900 DPI|Razer DeathAdder Elite||'
```

I have looked at the [documentation for dbus](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/), but i have given up trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

As it says at the top of the dbus documentation you linked to:

> dbus-python might not be the best D-Bus binding for you to use.

It may be better to use a more modern library like [pydbus](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus)

I don't have your setup to test but my best guess of how to convert the command:

```
qdbus org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar /id_10 org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar.pass '|A|<img src="/usr/local/share/icons/diybar/mouse.svg" height="22"/>900 DPI|Razer DeathAdder Elite||'
```

using pydbus would be

```
from pydbus import SessionBus

bus = SessionBus()
bar = bus.get('org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar', '/id_10')

bar.pass('|A|<img src="/usr/local/share/icons/diybar/mouse.svg" height="22"/>900 DPI|Razer DeathAdder Elite||')
```

Comment: Syntax error at the p in bar.pass - https://pastebin.com/WNrQrMz0

Comment: What output do you get if you do `print(dir(bar))`?

Comment: A error telling me that pydbus is not installed, how does a distro that not ship with python2 not have a modern python dbus library installed stock for python3, upon fixing that i get this: https://pastebin.com/QGs6paGD Note: installing pydbus does not fix the syntax error

Comment: I don't understand why you are getting a syntax error because `pass` is in the list of functions available for `bar`

Comment: i think that pass is a python key word, i tried using `bar['pass']('str')` but i just got a key error

Comment: the issue is 100% the property name being `pass` i edited the applet and made a `pysafepass` that is a copy of `pass` and using `bar.pysafepass('string')` does work