# Python keyword pass causing syntax errors, is this a bug in the language?

Tags: python, dbus

I was working with [this KDE widget](https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/do-it-yourself-bar) and was having hard time trying to access it with python, I figured out with some [help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70060099/7721752) that I was trying to do it right originally and if I patch the 2 files below in the widget to change the name from `pass` to say `pypass` or just add a copy of this `pass` feature under a new name I can use the new name no problem, is this a false positive in the syntax check or just a usage issue? is there a way to work around this issue?

- [plugin/DBusService.cpp](https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/do-it-yourself-bar/blob/master/plugin/DBusService.cpp) (line 6: `void DBusService::pass(QString data) {`)
- [plugin/DBusService.hpp](https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/do-it-yourself-bar/blob/master/plugin/DBusService.hpp) (line 16: `void pass(QString data);`)

These give a syntax error cause of the word `pass`

```
#!/bin/python3
from pydbus import SessionBus
diy=SessionBus().get("org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar","/id_10")
diy.pass('|A|Label|Tooltip|notify-send hello world|')
```

```
#!/bin/python3
from dbus import SessionBus
diy=SessionBus().get_object("org.kde.plasma.doityourselfbar","/id_10")
diy.pass('|A|Label|Tooltip|notify-send hello world|')
```

I did try to set it like this but I just get a Key Error, so much for it behaving like JavaScript...

- `diy['pass]('string')`

Comment: Perhaps it is because `pass` is a reserved word in python: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords.

Comment: Here's a lifelong tip you can apply over and over: if you're new to a programming language, and it's not behaving the exact way you expect: chances are quite likely it's not "a bug in the language".

Comment: Use `pass_` instead. this is a common idiom for (other) reserved words like `raise`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not "a bug in the language", you just can't do that, because `pass` is a language keyword. I don't know if pydbus provides a nice way for calling a method by name, bypassing its proxies, but if it doesn't, you should be able to do

```
getattr(diy, 'pass')('string')
```